# League of Legends installed with playonlinux: updater crashes before the PLAY window runs

Tags: 16.04, wine, launcher, games, playonlinux

I recently had to boot my pc clean with a new 16.04 and can't seem to get League of Legends working like I used to before the pc reset. I installed AdobeAir and the latest wine, however there seems to be something else wrong.

Running the program through terminal yields (for those interested):

```
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for lol.launcher.admin.exe

[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-2.7-staging lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/capo/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)

[POL_Wine] Message: Notice: PlayOnLinux deliberately disables winemenubuilder. See http://www.playonlinux.com/fr/page-26-Winemenubuilder.html

[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  165
Current serial number in output stream:  169
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "windows vista" in the POL wine settings.

I would also recommend activating the virtual desktop setting with your screen resolution in the wine settings and disabling "close client ingame" in lol-settings. If the shop doesn't work you might have to install "Internet Explorer" under "install components" in POL.

You might find further help at [reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/).